# Django admin filter, Add two field in to template

Tags: django, django-admin

I wanted to create a filter to get some value range. there I want to get 2 numbers in to `parameter_name` for that i added 2 number field. like bellow image.

[image]

If I use only one field, value of that field can be get. as `value = self.value()`

```
<input type="number" step="0.1" max="0.9" min="0.1" id="IsWithinRange" name="IsWithinRange">
```

But i need these 2 values so added another field, then non of their value can get. `self.value()` always is Non.
now I cannot figure out how can I pass this value to my filter. can anyone direct me to the correct path.

Comment: That is a good question but I'm afraid it's not an easy task to do. That's because the filters are not "fixed" in the way Django wants it. So, because filter values are defined by the user (even if you had one input field), you have to use `jQuery` in order to send this `GET`request and handle it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be not the exact answer. but using this you might be able to fulfill the requirement.
※If there are more than one input fields the Django filter will not work properly. Therefore have to use one input field per a filter.
(Use Jquery slider to select range rather than using two input fields)

Python class

```
class IsWithinRangeFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):

title = 'Title'
parameter_name = 'scoreRange'
template = '[path]/input_filter.html'

def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
    return (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
    )

def queryset(self, request, queryset):

    value = self.value()
    try:
        if value:

            #do whatever

    except Exception as e:
        logger.info('#####ERROR{}' .format(e))

    return queryset
```

call the filter class

```
list_filter = (IsWithinRangeFilter,)
```

input_filter.html

```html
{% load i18n %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    var lowerRange = 5;
    var upperRange = 8;   

    $( function() {
      $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        values: [ lowerRange, upperRange ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            if(ui.values[ 0 ] === ui.values[ 1 ])
            {
                return false;
            }
            $( "#scoreRange" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ]/10 + " - " + ui.values[ 1 ]/10 );
        }
      });
      $( "#scoreRange" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) / 10 +
        " - " + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) / 10 );
    } );
    
</script>

{% block content %}
<h3>{% Any Title %}</h3>

<ul>
    <li>
        <form>
            <p>
                <label >Any Description</label>
                <div id="slider-range"></div>
                <label style="font-weight: bold;">Filter：</label><input type="submit" id="scoreRange" name="scoreRange" style="margin:5px; text-align:center; background-color:#79aec8; cursor:pointer; border:0; color:#f7f5f3; font-weight:bold;">
            </p>            
        </form>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

hope this will help!!!